# Adding extra +++ in my $variable

Tags: php

```
$ans = db2_result($queryexe, 'ANS');
```

My $ans is five character long. I only use two characters for this project.

So when i print my url with $ans it will look something like this.

```
www.myurl.com/&int1=MC
```

and this is how i print it

```
print("<td> <a href='www.myurl.com/&int1=$ans'>$ans</a></td>\n");
```

I wonder how i can modify my $ans to be $ans with three + after, like this one under

www.myurl.com/&int1=MC+++

I need those 3 extra +++ to make my other code work.

Any suggetions? Sorry if i made myself unclear what i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` has a special meaning in the query string (it's the space char).
If you want preserve its value you should url-encode the string.

```
print("<td> <a href='www.myurl.com/&int1=".urlencode($ans)."'>$ans</a></td>\n");
```

Comment: Thank you for ur fast answear, but with urlencode i got 9 extra +

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
www.myurl.com/&int1=MC%2B%2B%2B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat + sign.

add something like.

> $ans = (strlen($ans) == 5) ? $ans : $ans.str_repeat("+", 5-strlen($ans));

it will convert

**mc  => mc+++**

**abc => abc++**

**a   => a++++**

**abcde => abcde**

Comment: Sounds like a good answear, but my ans is still without any +++